# Determine NetSuite SuiteTalk PurchaseOrderItem Type

Tags: netsuite

How can you determine if a PurchaseOrderItem is an Inventory Item or Noninventory Item?

Using NetSuite's SuiteTalk web service, I locate a specific PurchaseOrder based on a PO Number.  From the purchaseOrder object, I can see the item list representing the purchaseOrderItems.

```
PurchaseOrderItem[] purchaseOrderItems = purchaseOrder.itemList.item;
```

I am able to enumerate the PurchaseOrderItems.

I would like to include some additional information such as whether each item is an Inventory Item or Noninventory Item.  Also, for NonInventory Items, I need to determine if it is fulfillable.  In NetSuite's UI can see this information by clicking the name of the item and looking at the "Can be fulfilled/received" (Field ID: isfulfillable).

Things I have tried:

I had some success with the following test code. It grabs the item.internalID and attempts to "get" a specific RecordType. I repeat this for all record types I am interested in.  I am not comfortable with this solution.

I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction to solve this problem.

```
<!-- language: c# -->
// Look up inventory item
RecordRef recordRefInventoryItem = new RecordRef();
recordRefInventoryItem.internalId = poItem.item.internalId;
recordRefInventoryItem.type = RecordType.inventoryItem;
recordRefInventoryItem.typeSpecified = true;
ReadResponse responseInventoryItem = netSuiteService.get(recordRefInventoryItem);
if (responseInventoryItem.status.isSuccess)
{
    InventoryItem inventoryItem = (InventoryItem)responseInventoryItem.record;    
}

// Look up non inventory item
RecordRef recordRefNonInventoryItem = new RecordRef();
recordRefNonInventoryItem.internalId = poItem.item.internalId;
recordRefNonInventoryItem.type = RecordType.nonInventoryPurchaseItem;
recordRefNonInventoryItem.typeSpecified = true;
ReadResponse responseNonInventoryItem = netSuiteService.get(recordRefNonInventoryItem);
if (responseNonInventoryItem.status.isSuccess)
{
    NonInventoryPurchaseItem nonInventoryPurchaseItem = (NonInventoryPurchaseItem)responseNonInventoryItem.record;
bool isFulfillable = nonInventoryPurchaseItem.isFulfillable;
}
```

**Follow up after bknights suggestion.**

I created the following code to extract the internalIDs of the items, and perform a ItemSearchAdvanced search to qualify them.  The following code returns a strongly typed result.recordList.

```
List<RecordRef> itemIds = new List<RecordRef>();
foreach (PurchaseOrderItem purchaseOrderItem in purchaseOrderItems)
{
    RecordRef recordRef = new RecordRef();
    recordRef.internalId = purchaseOrderItem.item.internalId;                    
    itemIds.Add(recordRef);
}

// configure a search to locate 'anyOf' itemIds
SearchMultiSelectField searchMultiSelectField = new SearchMultiSelectField();
searchMultiSelectField.searchValue = itemIds.ToArray();
searchMultiSelectField.@operator = SearchMultiSelectFieldOperator.anyOf;
searchMultiSelectField.operatorSpecified = true;

// tell the system we want 'internalID' 'anyOf' itemIds
ItemSearchBasic itemSearchBasic = new ItemSearchBasic();
itemSearchBasic.internalId = searchMultiSelectField;

// create an item search
ItemSearch itemSearch = new ItemSearch();
itemSearch.basic = itemSearchBasic;

// create an item search advanced
ItemSearchAdvanced itemSearchAdvanced = new ItemSearchAdvanced();
itemSearchAdvanced.criteria = itemSearch;

SearchResult result = NS.search(itemSearchAdvanced);

if (result.status.isSuccess)
{
    // results.recordList has strongly type items.  Yeah!
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I tend to do is to collect all my item internal ids and then do a ItemSearchAdvanced with the list of item ids. This allows you to pull all the item types, sub-types and isFullfillable values for the item records.

The other way you can do this is to source those values into hidden custcol fields on the transaction.

Comment: Thank you bknights.  I attempted your suggestion, but I was not able to return any records using an ItemSearchAdvanced.  If possible, could you look at the code I added above, at let me know if I am heading down a similar direction as your first suggestion.

Comment: I found the problem.  Missed adding   searchMultiSelectField.operatorSpecified = true;
I will update the topic above.  Thank you for your assistance.